# entire function that misses $[0,1]$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function.

Suppose that $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}:f(z)\not\in[0,1]$.

Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

I've heard about Picard's little theorem, but we didn't cover it and I am interested if there is another proof for this special case.

Comment: There will be a nonconstant holomorphic map $g$ from the complement of $[0,1]$ to the unit disc. Apply Liouville to $g\circ f$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Shouldn't $g$ be injective?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, I think that the solution you deleted is much more natural.

Comment: @DonFanucci: I deleted my answer here when I realized that the question has been asked and answered before. I have added it to the other question instead.